# using jquery to click on the first radio button with a display not set to none

Tags: jquery, css

so i'm trying to check a radio button that's contained in a div. I'm trying to get to the first radio button who's parent is the first in a set that is not hidden. here's what the code looks like:

```
<div class="form-rectangles">
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="108" style="display: none;">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-108" value="108" checked="">
        <span class="rectangle-text">1 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="109" style="display: none;">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-109" value="109">
        <span class="rectangle-text">2 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="110">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-110" value="110">
        <span class="rectangle-text">4 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="111">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-111" value="111">
        <span class="rectangle-text">8 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="112">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-112" value="112">
        <span class="rectangle-text">16 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="113">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-113" value="113">
        <span class="rectangle-text">32 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="114">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-114" value="114">
        <span class="rectangle-text">128 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="106">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-106" value="106">
        <span class="rectangle-text">90 Capsules</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="107">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-107" value="107">
        <span class="rectangle-text">1000 Capsules Bulk</span>
      </label>
  </div>
```

So, in this case, i'm trying to check the id="attribute-110" radio button. It's the first in the group of radio buttons that is in the first visible label. I figure it's something like this:

```
$('.form-label:visible:first radio:first').click(); //?
```

You input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: define `input[type="radio"]`.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but on _'.form-lablel:visible:first radio:first'_ you've mispelled "label".

Comment: lol... i'll edit that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution was almost correct. Remember to target `input` elements with the type of radio using the jQuery selector `:radio` which is shorthand for `[type=radio]`

Unless you have any event handlers for the click event, you should prefer to set the `checked` property to true, instead of clicking it.

```
$('.form-label:visible:first :radio:first').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

A little change in your selector: use `input[type=radio]` instead of just `radio`.

```js
$('.form-label:visible:first input[type=radio]:first').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-rectangles">
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="108" style="display: none;">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-108" value="108" checked="">
        <span class="rectangle-text">1 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="109" style="display: none;">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-109" value="109">
        <span class="rectangle-text">2 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="110">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-110" value="110">
        <span class="rectangle-text">4 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="111">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-111" value="111">
        <span class="rectangle-text">8 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="112">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-112" value="112">
        <span class="rectangle-text">16 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="113">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-113" value="113">
        <span class="rectangle-text">32 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="114">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-114" value="114">
        <span class="rectangle-text">128 oz</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="106">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-106" value="106">
        <span class="rectangle-text">90 Capsules</span>
      </label>
      <label class="form-label rectangle" data-product-attribute-value="107">
        <input type="radio" name="attribute[786]" id="attribute-107" value="107">
        <span class="rectangle-text">1000 Capsules Bulk</span>
      </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your code. in the selector you wrote "lablel" instead of "label". Try fixing this and if it still doesn't work try

`$('.form-label:visible input[type=radio]').first().click();`

which should get the first element found as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.form-lablel:visible:first radio:first').click();`

Your code above have 2 issues:

1. `.form-lablel` is wrong spelling. Should become `.form-label`
2. `radio:first` change to `input[type="radio"]`

And this should work well.